# CSS file and inspector don't match

Tags: css, wordpress, web-inspector

I am working on a WordPress site. I've changed one line of CSS, but no matter what I do it's not reflecting that change in my local development environment. I've tried shutting down and restarting everything and it still doesn't match. I thought that maybe another rule was overriding it, but the inspector shows it is coming from the exact same line in my CSS file. I've checked this in both Chrome and Firefox. I'm at a loss for why the browser isn't receiving the change.

CSS

```
.entry-content p {
        margin-bottom: 10px;
    }
```

Inspector

```
.entry-content p {
        margin: 0;
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried `margin-bottom: 10px !important` ?

Comment: Yup that doesn't work either, but it also doesn't show up in the inspector when I refresh the page

Comment: Found the solution. Not sure why, but I've fixed it now haha.

Comment: It sounds to me like a caching issue... Could you share your solution for future devs that land on this page.

Comment: Certainly! So I'm using Local by Flywheel in conjunction with WAMP for my local hosting. I realized that this morning I was just using Local and manually refreshing the page to see my changes. I ran "npm run dev" in the terminal to get browser sync working and that fixed it!

Answer (score 0):

The most common reason would be browser caching. When you enqueue a script or stylesheet with WordPress, the `wp_enqueue_script` and `wp_enqueue_style` functions allow you to specify a "version" in the 4th parameter. This version is appended to your URL like so `?ver=`.

You can take advantage of this, by having your server read the last time that your CSS or JS file was modified (using [filemtime()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.filemtime.php)) and using that as the version number. This will ensure that your file never gets cached, as a change to the file will result in a new URL.

I've included an example below:

```php
function enqueue_scripts()
{
    $relative_path = '/style.css';

    wp_enqueue_style( 'my-script', get_theme_file_uri( $relative_path ), [], filemtime( get_theme_file_path( $relative_path ) ) );
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_scripts' );
```

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to determine what exactly caused your issue, so my answer will focus on what *may* have caused it.

## Browser cache

Web-browsers temporarily save the CSS files and will not request them for a while to reduce resource waste. When that caching period ends, the browser will request that file again.

You may want to change the `link` tag loading the file whenever it's changed by adding some URL parameter, like `?version=1234` and change that each time the CSS has changed.

## Server cache

In some cases it's labor-intensive for a server to generate a page each time a request is addressing it. For this purpose static web-pages are being generated and while that static file's lifecycle is not over, you will always get the old version. You could clear the server cache, which is a drastic measure, or ensure that the given file's cache only is invalidated, depending on what server-caching you are using.

## Wrong file

It's possible that there are several copies of the same file and you applied a fix for one copy and the other copy still has the old version. Search for the file and see whether there are more than one copy for it.

## Server tools

You might have some server tools which preprocess CSS files before sending them. An example is the minifier. While your source file may have been correctly changed, it is possible that an unchanged obfuscated copy of that file is in use.